# What will the result be if I multiply a non-diagonal metric by a non-diagonal inverse metric?

Tags: tensors

I know that multiplying a diagonal metric and its inverse is kronocker delta. But I wonder whether this holds up if tensors are not diagonal or not?

Answer (score 2):

If $g_{ij}$ are the components of a metric and $g^{ij}$ denote the inverse components, then $g^{ij}g_{jk} = \delta^i_k$ regardless of whether or not $[g_{ij}]$ is diagonal. This is just the statement that for an invertible matrix $A$ we have $A^{-1}A = I$ regardless of whether or not $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wonder, if j and k are not equal does the result  have to be 0? If it does, Could you show it?

Comment: Yes, it has to be zero, that's what the Kronecker delta means. What do you mean by show it? How are you defining $g^{ij}$?

Comment: I mean do you know why is it kronecker delta? It makes sense that if the indices are the same it is 1 but I couldn't wrap my head around the second option.

Comment: İs it because the definiton of the identity matrix? Diagonals are 1, off-diagonals are 0.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The $g^{ij}$ are defined to be the components of the inverse, so $g^{ij}g_{jk} = \delta^j_k$ by definition.

Comment: So it is kronecker delta because of the definition of the identity matrix. Thank you for your time and answers.